# Pycharm, keep getting Flow Tool panel with "Error: Flow executable path is incorrect"

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, flowtype

After updating to Pycharm 2017.2.1 I got this Flow Tool panel (although not having flow installed) which pops up and I can not get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. A workaround is [mentioned](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27270):
edit .idea/workspace.xml and remove the

```
  <component name="JsFlowSettings">
     ... 
  </component>
```

section

Another workaround which seemed to work for me:
select Flow under [file/settings/languages&frameworks/javascript] as Javascript Language version and untick all flow settings options that then appear.